# Spring Integration @Scheduled not working due to @Poller

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have a Spring Boot / Spring Integration application running that makes use of `@Poller` in Spring Integration and also `@Scheduled` on another method in a mostly-unrelated class. The `@Poller` is for polling an FTP server for new files. However I've found that it seems like the `@Poller` is somehow interfering with my `@Scheduled` method.

The `@Poller` has `maxMessagesPerPoll = -1` so that it will process as many files as it can get. However, when I first start my application, there are over 100 files on the FTP server, so it's going to process them all. What I have found is that, if these files are being processed, then the `@Scheduler` stops triggering at all.

For example, if I set my `@Scheduled` to have a `fixedDelay = 1` to trigger every millisecond and then start my application, the `@Scheduled` method will trigger a few times, until the `@Poller` triggers and begins processing messages, at which point my `@Scheduled` method completely stops triggering. I assumed that simply there was some task queue that was being filled by the `@Poller` so I simply needed to wait for all of the messages to be processed, but even after the `@Poller` is completely done and has processed all of the files, the `@Scheduled` method still does not trigger at all.

My thoughts are that maybe there is some task queue that is being filled by the `@Poller`, which is breaking my `@Scheduled` method, but if so, I still don't see any way that I can use a separate task queue for the different methods, or any other possible options for customizing or fixing this issue.

Does anyone have any idea what might be happening to my `@Scheduled` method, and how can I fix this?

`@Poller`:

```
    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "ftpChannel", poller = @Poller(cron = "0/5 * * ? * *", maxMessagesPerPoll = "-1"))
    public MessageSource<InputStream> myMessageSource() {
        //Build my message source
        return messageSource;
    }
```

`@Scheduled`:

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 6000)
public void myScheduledMethod(){
  //Do Stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

They do use the same bean name for their scheduler `taskScheduler`.

It should only be a problem if you have 10 or more pollers (the default scheduler bean configured by Spring Integration has a pool size of 10 by default). A common mistake is having many queue channels (which hold on to scheduler threads for a second at a time, by default).

If you only have one poller, and not a lot of queue channels, I can't explain why you would get thread starvation.

You can increase the pool size - see [Configuring the Task Scheduler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.4.RELEASE/reference/html/configuration.html#namespace-taskscheduler).

Or you can use a different scheduler in the `ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`.

Answer (score 2):

As already [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60713670/13629651), the problem is linked to task schedulers having the same name, although it may occur even if there are fewer than 10 pollers. Spring Boot auto-configuration provides scheduler with default pool size of 1 and registration of this scheduler may happen before the registration of `taskScheduler`, provided by Spring Integration.

Configuring task scheduler via [Spring Integration properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.4.RELEASE/reference/html/configuration.html#global-properties) doesn't help as this bean doesn't get registered at all. But providing own instance of `TaskScheduler` with adjusted pool size, changing pool size of auto-configured scheduler via `spring.task.scheduling.pool.size` property or excluding `TaskSchedulingAutoConfiguration` should solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

In our case, the Poller was used by inbound-channel-adapter to access mail from the IMAP server - but when it polls for an email with large attachments, it blocks the thread used by @Scheduled as it only uses a single thread for scheduling the task.
So we set the Spring property spring.task.scheduling.pool.size=2 - which now allows the @Scheduled method to run in a different thread even if the poller gets blocked (in a different thread) when trying to fetch mail from IMAP server